# How do I print clear text from a windows form?

Tags: c#, winforms, printing, printdocument, blurry

I have successfully printed a windows form, but all the text is slightly blurry. I have concluded that this is a result of the resolution of the screen being much less than the resolution the printer uses. Is there a fundamental flaw in my approach or is there a way to reformat the text prior to printing so that it comes out crisp?

```
void PrintImage(object o, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    int x = SystemInformation.WorkingArea.X;
    int y = SystemInformation.WorkingArea.Y;
    int width = panel1.Width;
    int height = panel1.Height;

    Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);

    Bitmap img = new Bitmap(width, height);

    this.DrawToBitmap(img, bounds);
    Point p = new Point(100, 100);
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, p);
}

private void BtnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btnPrint.Visible = false;
    btnCancel.Visible = false;
    if(txtNotes.Text == "Notes:" || txtNotes.Text == "")
    {
        txtNotes.Visible = false;
    }
    PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
    pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(PrintImage);
    pd.Print();
}
```

Comment: I think you'd be better off using `DrawString` instead of `DrawImage`. Maybe try a test `DrawString` and see if the text is sharp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a fundamental flaw in my approach [...] ?

Yes.

1. You take the size of `panel1` to calculate the size of the image. Later, you let `this` draw to the image, but `this` is the form, not the panel.
2. What makes you think that `SystemInformation.WorkingArea` is related to the window you want to print?
3. You should take a bit more care of disposable objects.

> [...] is there a way to reformat the text prior to printing so that it comes out crisp?

There's not a general way which would allow you to scale all other controls as well.

However, instead of blurry text, you can get crisp pixelated text by scaling the bitmap up by a certain factor using the `NearestNeighbor` mechanism.

Here's the difference in a PDF generated without scaling (left) and a factor of 3 scaling (right) at the same zoom level in Acrobat Reader (click to enlarge):

[image: Image in result.]

Here's the scaling code, also without fixing any disposable issues:

```
        this.DrawToBitmap(img, bounds);
        Point p = new Point(100, 100);
        img = ResizeBitmap(img, 3);
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, p);
    }

    private static Bitmap ResizeBitmap(Bitmap source, int factor)
    {
        Bitmap result = new Bitmap(source.Width*factor, source.Height*factor);
        result.SetResolution(source.HorizontalResolution*factor, source.VerticalResolution*factor);
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(result))
        {
            g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;
            g.DrawImage(source, 0, 0, source.Width*factor, source.Height*factor);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Marked this correct as it did help me greatly, and does answer the question. @BlorgBeard had it right though, this all needs to be done with drawstring. Thanks to both of you, huge help.

Comment: @SomeNerdAtWork: there's no `string` in your code at all, which made me think that you don't have a `string`

Comment: The code in my initial post has been completely reworked, thanks for the input though.